# Change name of webcam from windows registry programmatically

Tags: windows-10, powershell, cmd.exe, windows-registry, webcam

I want to change the name of a selected web camera in windows 10 so that the given name will be shown to other applications (zoom/meet) instead of the default webcam name. I have seen that I can change the camera name by changing the key `FriendlyName` of the following registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_046D&PID_082B&MI_00#6&8a7015f&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\#GLOBAL\Device Parameters
```

But I am sure this is not static for all computers. How can I get this value programmatically (say run a script to change the name) so that it will work in any Windows 10 machine?

Comment: Look to see if it is there before trying to take any action at all, just as you would with any other filesystem item. The registry is just a drive relative to a PowerShell use case and you can use ti like one when searching for items. [Get-PSDrive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive?view=powershell-7).

Comment: Yes but my question was how to use that "filesystem" to rename a camera name?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

---

- For **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**:

```
@echo off && cd /d "%~dp0"

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims= " %%T in ('"%__AppDir__%robocopy.exe" /L . . /njh /njs')do set^ "_tab=%%~T"

for /f skip^=1^eol^=^|^tokens^=*delims^=^%_tab%^  %%i in ('
%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like '%%Cam%%'" get DeviceID^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe .
')do <con: ^< nul set^ "_HKey=%%~i"

for /f eol^=^|^tokens^=1-2delims^=^%_tab%^  %%g in ('
%__AppDir__%Reg.exe Query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\%_HKey%"^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe "FriendlyName DeviceDesc"
')do ^< nul %__AppDir__%Reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\%_HKey:  =%" /f /v %%~g /t %%~h /d "EasyCamera"

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- In PowerShell  // The same mechanics in PowerShell would be...

```
$VidStr=Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *cam* | Where-Object {$_.InstanceId -like “*\VID*“} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'InstanceId'; 
$RegStr=Join-Path -Path HKLM:SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum -ChildPath $VidStr -Resolve; $Old_is=Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *cam* | 

Where-Object {$_.InstanceId -like “*\VID*“} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'FriendlyName' ; if (Test-Path -Path $RegStr) { 
   Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegStr -Name FriendlyName -Value New_Camera_Name
      Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegStr -Name DeviceDesc -Value New_Camera_Name  
  }
```

---

**1** Get the part of register `HKLM\...\ENUN` path for change register using wmic:

```
wmic.exe path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like '%%Cam%%'" get DeviceID

rem :: returns :: 
USB\VID_174F&PID_116A&MI_00\6&233A6595&0&0000"
```

**2** With `reg query`, you can easily find the `description` and `friendly` name by concatenating with `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\` and previous output:

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\USB\VID_174F&PID_116A&MI_00\6&233A6595&0&0000"
```

**3**  Use the `Req Query` outputs to execute you register changes:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_174F&PID_116A&MI_00\6&233A6595&0&0000" /f /v FriendlyName /t REG_SZ /d "New_Camera_Name"

C:\Windows\System32\Reg.exe add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USB\VID_174F&PID_116A&MI_00\6&233A6595&0&0000" /f /v DeviceDesc /t REG_SZ /d "New_Camera_Name"
```

---

**Obs.: 1** Without editing/changing registry key permission, it will require you to run as administrator

**Obs.: 2** When renaming your camera to some string that does not fit within originally (**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)** ***`%%Cam%%`*** and/or in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)** ***`*cam*`***), an edit will have to be made for future executions in:

- ```
  "Description like %%Fit_New_String_Name%%"
  ```
- ```
  $VidStr = Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName *Fit_New_String_Name*
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. But I was not trying to change the camera name from the "Device Manager", I want to change the "Name" of the camera so that it shows the name in other applications (Zoom, Google Meet etc.)

Comment: @RahatZaman Thanks for your comment, the reg key (`...##?#USB#VID_...`) was not found in my computer, I 'll see/try in another one in next days..

Comment: @RahatZaman did you manage to do it?

Comment: @RahatZaman  I do try, but no positive results

Comment: i tried on windows 10, it changes in device manager yes, but whenever i open google or windows camera app it still show a default name, i tried restarting even but doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help each cam has a id to find that use ffmpeg.exe in same folder make a bat file put this in it

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy -hide_banner

PAUSE
```

now look at the list looks like this

Alternative name "@device_pnp_\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0892&mi_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"

Just copy:

usb#vid_046d&pid_0892&mi_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}

now open up regedit in the line right above computer icon type this in that line:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses
now press enter on keyboard!

now go to edit find copy this and past it in it start with usb like this:

usb#vid_046d&pid_0892&mi_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}

now click find next
should find it what ever your vid_id is what you search for understand that ffmpeg shows you

now after that click on #global now click device parameters click twice on friendlyname and change the cams name click ok should rename your cams that way! Let me know if this helps anyone it rename your cams so they show up in other programs with out effecting the device managers names!!!

to find out the true key of the cams use this in a bat file

```
REG Query HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses /F "usb#vid_046d&pid_0892&mi_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}" /S > id_log.txt
```

just replace the usb#vid line with the cam id ffmpeg gives you it saves where the real reg key is in a file called id_log.txt

the real reg for that is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_046D&PID_0892&MI_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}
```

now you can program with that like got to the reg stuff like this

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_046D&PID_0892&MI_00#6&318e6641&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\#GLOBAL\Device Parameters
```

you could make a reg file and past this in it for the cam we need to rename
just put the name of the cam name you would like!

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_046D&PID_0892&MI_00#8&10943051&1&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\#GLOBAL\Device Parameters]
    "FriendlyName"="Name Of Cam Here"
```

so it would look like this!!!

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses\{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\##?#USB#VID_046D&PID_0892&MI_00#8&10943051&1&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\#GLOBAL\Device Parameters]
        "FriendlyName"="HD WEBCAM L-ROOM"
```

save as a webcamlroom.reg double click it say yes now your cam is renamed!!!

You can use ffmpeg to help you program your cams also like use the info it gives you like a program im working on some code in autohotkey

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

#include <UIA_Interface> ; Uncomment if you have moved UIA_Interface.ahk to your main Lib folder
;#include ..\Lib\UIA_Interface.ahk

UIA := UIA_Interface() ; Initialize UIA interface

DetectHiddenWindows On                 ; work with hidden windows

FileDelete, input.txt           ; delets a txt file called input.txt, So we can creat a new one later.
Run %comspec% /k ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy -hide_banner PAUSE,,Hide,PID  ; "/k keeps the cmd window open /c would close it, make sure ffmpeg.exe is in the same  folder  use cmd.exe to run your command
Sleep 3000                              ; give it time to start, change title
WinWait %ComSpec% ahk_pid %PID%        ; wait until title reset = work done
WinActivate ahk_pid %PID%              ; activate to send keys, ControlSend fails at ALT
ClipBoard =                            ; clear Clipboard
SendInput !{Space}es{Enter}            ; select/copy everything
ClipWait 2                             ; wait until Clipboard is set up
FileAppend, %Clipboard%, input.txt ; <-- process the result in Clipboard and makes a txt file called input.txt past results in it!
WinClose ahk_pid %PID%                 ; close cmd window

FileRead, Source, input.txt
FileDelete, output1.txt           ; Remove previous output1.txt file
RE=U)(["']\b)(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1               ; Pattern for strings in quotes. take out \b to just have text with out "" around it!
StartPos=1
Loop
{
    FoundPos:=RegExMatch(Source, RE, Found, StartPos)   ; looks for matches of the pattern and selects only what the pattern is!
    If not FoundPos
        Break
    StartPos:=FoundPos+StrLen(Found)
    FileAppend                                   ; creats the output1.txt file with results!
    , % Found1 ? Found . "`n" : ""
      , output1.txt
}


FileRead inputtext, output1.txt
FileDelete, output.txt
regp := "(?mi)(is)*.*webcam(is)*.*"

Pos := 1
while(Pos := RegExMatch(inputtext, regp, M, Pos + StrLen(M)))
    outputv .= M "`n"

FileAppend % outputv, output.txt
```